# Python - Getting a for loop error: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, indexing

Im stuck with one piece of my code and i cant seem to find the answer to solve the error

I keep getting the following error message but doesn't make sense:

```
temp = times[i].split(', ')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As context, I’m **scraping** a website to get information on log in dates and times, it retrieves the text version of the log in date and time so im in the middle of converting the time into a datetime object so that i can then subtract another datetime object and find out if the person was late or not

My first step is to separate by comma (,) the date and the time (both are in a single string), then convert the time into a datetime object and add an if statement at the end to confirm if the log in time is < than the start of the shift and pop the item from the list if it is true

If i were to remove the IF statement, the error goes away which is kind of strange, and if i were to reduce the list by one it also goes away

```
from datetime import datetime, date

times  = ['5/1/2020, 8:08:54', '5/1/2020, 10:07:09', '5/1/2020, 10:27:49', '5/1/2020, 10:53:14',
'5/1/2020, 11:57:46', '5/1/2020, 12:53:38', '5/1/2020, 2:04:52', '5/1/2020, 2:14:55']

#Analysts Shift
schedule = datetime.strptime('8:05:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()

for i in range(len(times)):
    temp = times[i].split(', ')
    a = datetime.strptime(temp[1], '%H:%M:%S').time()
    if datetime.combine(date.today(), a) < datetime.combine(date.today(), schedule):
        times.pop(i)

print(times)
```

Comment: `times.pop(i)` you are destructively mutating a list while iterating over it, this is generally a bad idea. `range(len(times))` sets up a `range` object whose length is the length of the original list, but you are making that very list smaller in the loop, so that `i` eventually exceeds the length of the mutated list.

Comment: I think i will end up creating a new list, that doesn't give me an error message, i will replace times.pop() with newlist.append(times[i]) or the like

Comment: That is definitely more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

change your for loop to:

```
for i in range(len(times)-1):
```

Comment: How would that help? If there is more than 1 `pop()` during the looping, the same error would happen.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Well, the only solution is then create a new list, and store the needed values inside it. Instead of removing the wrong ones from the list that we iterate.

Comment: It is probably not the only way, but it is the idiomatic way.